# Populate multiple cells based on the option selected in a dropdown menu

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

First off I want to apologize for asking a question that's been answered multiple times, but I've spent the past hours reading and trying to figure out each and every one of them without success.

Here is a link to a sample spreadsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12uB8lmhmL2ZTKSZYdq0ZAvE-mfznqpq7p2PjNia3qUw/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, on the sheet "Level Stats" I'm trying to populate the cells B3 to B37 based on the item selected on the dropdown located in the cell B2.
In the spreadsheet "Base Stats" are the corresponding values I'm trying to import when a specific option is selected in the dropdown menu.
For instance if "Start HP is the option selected, I'd like the cells B3 to B37 of this same sheet to be populated with the value of the cells D3 to D37 from the "Base Stats" spreadsheet (where the column is labeled "Start HP" as well.

Is this actually achievable?
I cannot understand any of the tutorials I tried, and I'm unable to import the formulas from other posts either, I get errors returned on everything I tried (hlookup, vlookup, etc..).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B3 try

```
=filter('Base Stats'!C3:1000; 'Base Stats'!C1:1=B1)
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: It works! thank you very much :) 
if you have extra minute, would you mind explaining the formula?